# Improve code "content changer"

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to improve my as I call it "contenthandler". What it does is that it changes different articles when I click different buttons. Im happy on how it works, but I feel this is not the best practise and I want some advices on how to maybe shorten it even more or use any other way to do this.

Im not intrested in any jQuery or other libaries at the moment.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var article = document.getElementsByClassName("test"); // Article becomes an array.
  var buttonClick = e.target.className;
  switch (buttonClick){
    case "one":
      test(article);
      article[0].style.display = "";
      break; 
    case "two":
      test(article);
      article[1].style.display = "";
      break; 
    case "three":
      test(article);
      article[2].style.display = "";
      break;
  }
  function test(article){
    for (var i = 0; i < article.length; i++){
      article[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
//html
<ul>
  <li class="buttonNav"><h2 class="one">Show 1</h2></li>
  <li class="buttonNav"><h2 class="two">Show 2</h2></li>
  <li class="buttonNav"><h2 class="three">Show 3</h2></li>
</ul>
    <article class="test" style="display: none">1</article>
    <article class="test" style="display: none">2</article>
    <article class="test" style="display: none">3</article>
```

**[Edit]**

I remade the script from the answer I got, but I made a small change to it and made it dynamic so I do not need to hard code the "menu" in the script file.

```
var getClassName = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
var classNamesArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < getClassName.length; i++){
    classNamesArray.push(getClassName[i].className.toString());
};

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var article = document.getElementsByClassName("test"); // Article becomes an array.
    var buttonClick = e.target.className,
        // Maintain list of class names in an order
        validClassNames = classNamesArray,
        index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < validClassNames.length; i++) {
        if (buttonClick === validClassNames[i]) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index >= 0) {
        test(article);
        article[index].style.display = "";
    }
});

function test(article) {
    for (var i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
        article[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: to accept an answer click the tick beside it (hover and you will see it appear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I can think of is

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var article = document.getElementsByClassName("test"); // Article becomes an array.
    var buttonClick = e.target.className,
        // Maintain list of class names in an order
        validClassNames = ["one", "two", "three"],
        index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < validClassNames.length; i++) {
        if (buttonClick === validClassNames[i]) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index >= 0) {
        test(article);
        article[index].style.display = "";
    }
});

function test(article) {
    for (var i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
        article[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Also move the function definition to outside of the event handler.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3bct8r9a/5/)**

Comment: I liked the for-loop and the validClassNames, I will try your code later on. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I edited my original post. Remade your code check it out!